# Java, Jsoup, reading content from html page

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I was trying this code to read the content from a webpage,
i want to read the links, author names below the links and PDF or HTML links on the right side to my database or some doc file using Java.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

public class HTMLParserExample1 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Document doc;
      try {
         // need http protocol
         doc = Jsoup.connect("http://scholar.google.com/scholar?  l=en&q=visualization&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C4&as_sdtp=").userAgent("Chrome").get();

         Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
         Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
         for (Element link : links) {
            String linkHref = link.attr("href");
            String linkText = link.text();
            System.out.println("\nLinHREF: "+linkHref);
            System.out.println("linktext: "+linkText);
         }


      } catch (IOException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Above is my code, earlier it was giving me 403 error, but when i put useragent("Mozilla"), then its giving me null pointer exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at HTMLParserExample1.main(HTMLParserExample1.java:20)
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Please help.

Comment: I guess your link is wrong, it doesn't even work on my browser:)

Comment: http://scholar.google.com/scholar?  l=en&q=visualization&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C4&as_sdtp= this link is wrong, hence the problem

Answer (score 1):

Well it works for me if i remove spaces from url
`http://scholar.google.com/scholar?l=en&q=visualization&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C4&as_sdtp=`
is just fine. I strongly suggest to use Google API for web searches insteed of straight google parsing.
[Here some info about Gdata API](https://developers.google.com/gdata/).

Comment: Here the link has a 'h instead of the space, still am not able to get, is that the same code you are trying or you have your own.